# Twitter4j (tweets cannot be resolved)

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am currently developing a Twitter Crawler for my school project. I came across a lot of solutions searching through Google. This is what I ultimately came out with but always shows an error tweets cannot be resolved. I am not very experienced in coding if anyone can help me out I`ll be very grateful thank you. Here is my code:

```
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("***")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("***")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("***")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("***");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

//      twitter.updateStatus("Testing Twitter API");

        Query query = new Query("#iphone7");

        query.setCount(100);

        try {

            QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

            tweets.addAll(result.getTweets());

            System.out.println("Gathered " + tweets.size() + " tweets");

        } catch (TwitterException te) {

            System.out.println("Couldn't connect: " + te.toString());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't declared the variable tweets before trying to use it.

Comment: `tweets` remain undeclared.

Comment: I was not very sure what to declare tweets as it was not explained on any solutions I found but it seems I have to declare it as an ArrayList.

Comment: @Clement use this `List<Status> tweets = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me. I hope this example clarifies your doubt.

```
Query query = new Query(hashtag);
query.setCount(100);
          
//Execute the search method in the twitter object. 
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
out.println(result.getTweets().size());
for (Status status : result.getTweets()) 
   {
     out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + 
     status.getText());
     out.println();
   }
```